# Rails 4 - How to avoid double import of jQuery

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

The problem is, I have a theme that requires these two:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

So I tried disabling `jquery` in `application.js`

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
```

But when disabled there, it breaks the Rails RESTful link system:

```
<%= link_to "Log out", destroy_user_session_path, :method => :delete %>
```

So now I have both, `jquery` and `google jquery cdn` imported. I feel bad about that, any tips on how to fix it and satisfy both dependencies?

Comment: What do you mean it breaks the link system? Is there an error?

Comment: the `method: :delete` no longer works.

Comment: Ah yes, just leave jquery_ujs in there, it's different than jquery ui. jquery_ujs is the unobtrusive jquery adapter that makes those link work